# Managing Stale HTTP Read Operations with RxJS 5 (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular2-http

I've got an otherwise fairly standard SPA built on Angular 4 interfacing with a REST API.

Whenever the app performs a write operation to the API (put/post/delete), I want to abort all read operations (get).

I know I can achieve this via the takeUntil operator.

```
const write$ = new Subject<Date>();
public get(): Observable<Response> {
   return http.get().takeUntil(write$);
}

public update(): Observable<Response> {
   write$.next(new Date());
   return http.post();
}
```

What I want to do (and I'm struggling with) is expanding on this so that:

1. Aborted read operations are re-executed once there are no active write operations.
2. Read operations submitted while a write operation is in progress are buffered (caused to wait) until there are no active write operations.

The use case I think is pretty common.  Whenever the user modifies an entity, I update that entity's state immediately (as opposed to waiting for the write operation to complete). This makes the UI feel more responsive.  Read operations that are in-flight prior to the write, or that start after the write but complete before the write completes, result in the UI flipping the entity back to it's old state.

It is important that the mechanism for aborting/buffering/waiting on read operations be lossless.

***** **UPDATE** *****

I've come up with something that *appears* to be working, but it feels more complicated than I would like.  In addition to alternative solutions to the originally proposed problem, I would be interested in feedback on the following:

```
class ApiService {
    private asyncDelay = 25;
    private wait$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<Date>>(new BehaviorSubject<Date>(new Date()));
    private read$ = new Subject<Observable<Response>>();
    private buffer$ = new ReplaySubject<Observable<Response>>(1);

    constructor() {    
        const flush$ = new Subject<any>();
        this.read$.bufferToggle(this.wait$, () => flush$)
            .do(x => console.warn('FLUSH: ' + x.length))
            .switchMap(items => Observable.from(items))
            .subscribe(this.buffer$);

        this.wait$.switchMap(resume$ => {
            console.warn('WAIT')
            return resume$.switchMap(() => {
                console.warn('RESUMED')
                flush$.next(new Date());
                return Observable.merge(this.buffer$, this.read$)
                    .mergeAll();
            });
        })
        .subscribe();
    }

    protected get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {         
        const abort$ = this.wait$
            .skip(1)
            .take(1)
            .publishReplay(1)
            .do(() => console.warn('ABORT'));        

        const source$ = this.http.get(url, options) 
            .takeUntil(abort$)           
            .publishReplay(1);

        const retry$ = abort$.switchMap(() => Observable.timer(this.asyncDelay)
            .switchMap(() => this.get(url, options)))
            .takeUntil(source$)
            .publishReplay(1);

        this.read$.next(new Observable((observer: Observer<Response>) => {
            source$.catch(err => Observable.of(err))
              .subscribe(observer);

            source$.connect();
        }));        

        return Observable.race(source$, retry$)
            .take(1);
  }

  protected put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        const resume$ = new ReplaySubject<Date>(1);
        this.wait$.next(resume$.delay(this.asyncDelay).take(1));
        return this.http.put(url, body, options)
            .finally(() => resume$.next(new Date()));
  }

}
```

The idea is that read operations [`get()`] are returned in a published/disconnected state until it is confirmed they are eligible to execute (there is no pending write operation).

The subscriptions in the constructor run for the life of the application.

Any write operation [`put()`] results in an emission by the wait$ stream.  The emission is a resume$ stream that will emit exactly once when the write operation that originated the wait$ emission completes.

Anytime the wait$ stream emits, the innermost subscription responsible for connecting read$ operations is halted - additionally the bufferToggled read$ subscription is opened.

switchMap from the wait$ stream to it's resume$ emission insures that the innermost subscription responsible for connecting read$ operations is not re-started until the write operation that halted the previous subscription is completed.

if a subsequent write operation occurs prior to the completion of the previous, the wait$ stream simply re-starts, ultimately waiting for the new resume$ signal.  As I type this I realize that one assumption being made is that write operations will behave in a somewhat LILO fashion when it comes to completion timings.  I think this is OK in my particular use case.

Once the last emitted resume$ stream emits, the buffer$ is flushed, closed and merged with a real-time stream of new read$ operations.

The source$ stream returned by a call to `get()` is wired up to terminate in the event a write operation begins during it's execution.  Additionally, I construct a retry$ stream that ultimately begins with an emission from the wait$ stream.  I race() the source$ and retry$ stream... they are mutually exclusive in this case - it's only possible for one of them to emit.  If the source$ is terminated, the same signal responsible for terminating it starts the retry$ sequence which recurses back into `get()` and ultimately results in the retry response being buffered until all write operations complete.

... and the cycle repeats.

I don't know much about the underpinnings of RXJS, or the overhead involved in gorilla taping all of these operators and streams together as a means to an end.  My biggest concern at this point is leaking memory somewhere, and obviously readability for poor soul who needs to modify it 12+ months from now.

Comment: look at `waitUntil` operator

Comment: This logic also doesn't take into account a failure on the server side.  If you update the local state before confirmation of the server state's successful update, you risk having differing states on the local and server side.  The reason many developers will wait until the server responds is to allow the server to be the boss when it comes to the current state.  Showing the user that they successfully made a change, then reverting that because the server had an error is far more confusing than just making the user wait for the server to respond in the first place.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin in the case where the read operations may or may not be the result of polling, the problems regarding stale reads remains - even if I wait for confirmation on the write.  Also, the question is specifically asking for guidance on using RxJS5 to achieve a specific behavior, with the use case provided simply for context.  I'm not sure how you felt your comment was relevant.

Comment: @Hitmands the waitUntil operator does not appear to exist in RxJS5?

Comment: @josh-sachs it is skip until/while http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html